# neo4j constraints to ensure a Tuple to be unique

Tags: csv, file-upload, neo4j, cypher, constraints

I'm just wonderring how to deal with the following case. 
N.B: I need only hints.

I have a hierarchy on DB Like below.

```
+-CodeR
   +-R
     +-CodeC
          +-C
             +-CodeS
               +-S
```

**Is there a way to add constraints in neo4j to ensure that each Tuple of Names [FatherXNodeName,XNodeName,ChildXNodeName] is never repeated on my DB ?**

```
For example If I targeted Node R For update/delete I'would be certain That Tuple [CodeR,R,CodeC] is never repeated means [CodeR,R,CodeC] is totally different from Tuples 
#[R,CodeC,C], #[CodeC,C,CodeS], #[C,CodeS,S] and this should be applied to all the hierarchy.
```

R=Region C=City and S=Sector

Region={r1,r2,r3,...ri.,rn} where 1!= 2 != 3!=i !=n 
and 
City={c1,c2,c3,....,ck,cn} where 1!= 2 != 3!=k !=n 
and
Sector={s1,s2,s3,....,sj,sm} where 1!= 2 != 3!=i !=m

**But we could have ri=ck means region name equals city name**
and

CodeRegion={cr1,cr2,cr3,...cri.,crn} where 1!= 2 != 3!=i !=n 
and 
CodeCity={cc1,cc2,cc3,....,cck,ccn} where 1!= 2 != 3!=k !=n 
and
CodeSector={cs1,cs2,cs3,....,csj,csm} where 1!= 2 != 3!=i !=m

**But we could have cri=cck means code region equals code city name**

## Imagine

The csv line 504,NewYork,504,NewYork,504,Harlem

is uploaded to neo4j it will result implicitely on DB That hierarchy.

```
+-504
   +-NewYork
     +-504
          +-NewYork
             +-504
               +-Harlem
```

If I need to Apply update/or delte for example NewYork (Region name) Identified by Father codeRegion=504 and by ChildCodeCity=504 
but in that case we face the following problem:

which newYork are we talking about ? 
NewYork Region or newYork City 
the same imagination could be applied to codes for example if we need to update CodeCity which is 504 
we are talking about 504 that belongs to CodeC or CodeR or CodeS at the same time.

a workaround is to restrict nodes during creation(when inserting via UI or via csv lines uploading) to ensure that this case would never occur.

For that purpose, I made a java program to avoid that case. So when for the first time when wanna upload the csv file we pass it first to a validation step to validate the propsed csv file and reject the bad lines before uploading to neo4j. I made already this solution but this solution will work only for the first iteration of file upload. When the nodes are already alive on DB and we upload a csv file (with appended new lines) my java program will only check for the new appended one and not able to check also with the nodes that reside already on DB, a bad workaround solution would be to download those nodes residing on db to a csv and to always merge them to the proposed new csv file. But It would be costely in performance. and more if I want to simply insert a Node : example only new Region code OR new Region or New City code OR City OR new Sector code OR new Sector name VIA Rest api using UI my java program will not be of any use.

That s why I'm asking :

**Is there a way to add constraints in neo4j to ensure that each Tuple of Names [FatherXNodeName,XNodeName,ChildXNodeName] is never repeated on my DB ?**

Thank you very much.

## UPDATE DONE TO EXPLAIN MORE

First of all I have a csv file that I upload to neo4j.
The csv file is like

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7
a,b,a,d,e,f,g
h,i,h,i,h,ff,f27
f31,f32,f33,f34,f35,f36,f37
f41,f42,f43,f44,f45,f46,f47
f51,f52,f53,f54,f55,f56,f57
f61,f62,a,b,a,f66,f67
f71,f72,f73,f74,f75,f76,f77
f81,f82,f83,f84,f85,f86,f87
f91,f92,f93,f94,f95,f96,f97
f101,f102,f103,f104,f105,f106,f107
f111,f112,f113,f114,f115,f116,f117
f121,f122,f123,f124,f125,f126,f127
f131,f132,f133,f134,f135,f136,f137
f141,f142,f143,f144,f145,f146,f147
f151,f152,f153,f154,f155,f156,f157
f161,a,b,a,f165,f166,f167
i,h,ff,f174,f175,f176,f177
f181,f182,f183,f184,f185,f186,f187
f191,f192,f193,f194,f195,f196,f197
f201,f202,f203,f204,f205,f206,f207
f211,f212,f213,f214,f215,f216,f217
f221,f222,f223,f224,f225,f226,f227
f231,f232,f233,f234,f235,f236,f237
f241,f242,f243,f244,f245,f246,f247
f251,f252,f253,f254,f255,f256,f257
f261,f262,f263,f264,f265,f266,f267
f271,f272,f273,f274,f275,f276,f277
f281,f282,f283,i,h,ff,f287
fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4,fn5,fn6,fn7
f301,f302,f303,f304,f305,f306,f307
```

And before to upload that file to neo4j. 
I validate it programmatically  via java code for unacceptable entrie like has been Fully explained (You can escape the link because I resume it in below message)[FULL description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428372/detect-repeated-tuples-fi-j-1-fi-j-fi-j1-on-txt-file-using-java).

## unacceptable entries

unacceptable entrie in a line(or lines) are the lines that include a fi,j where a tuple [fi,(j-1), fi,j ,fi,j+1] existed already before or after in the txt file. i.e for a targeted field X detect if the field on the left XL and the field on the right XR don't match on any previous field in the txt file and hence if It matches we have to output: the filed X on the line Number is problematic because is the Tuple [XL,X,XR] is already defined on the previous Line number
and we diplay : - all The lines that will cause a conflict: That means, + The previous Line (that first occurence will be accepted on txt file reading) and + The problematic Lines(that follow The previous Line on txt file reading and hence would be ignored)
- The row number for accepted first occurence Tuple but accepted - The eventually row numbers for Not accepted Tuples that would be ignored - The Tuples [XL,X,XR] that cause the problem.

So  java code ensures message 's output for rejected lines on csv file like bellow.

OUTPUT

```
[h, i, h], Not accepted at all. rejected on lines: 3 
Line accepted is: empty
Line rejected : h,i,h,i,h,ff,f27

[a, b, a], Not accepted at all. rejected on lines: 2 
Line accepted is: empty
Line rejected : a,b,a,d,e,f,g

[i, h, ff] , accepetd on line  3  rejected on lines:  18 
Line rejected :  i,h,ff,f174,f175,f176,f177
 29 
Line rejected :  f281,f282,f283,i,h,ff,f287
```

Now after validating the file and uploaded successfully to neo4j.

I end up with three nodes.

```
R is the First  Node(is construct from the Pair (Field1,Field2))
C is the second Node(is construct from the Pair (Field3,Field4))
S is the third Node(is construct from the Pair (Field5,Field6_Field7))

R C S are linked by relationships like below :

(s:S)-[IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_R]->(r:R)<-[IS_A_C_BELONGING_TO]-(c:C)<-[IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_THAT_C]-(s)

And constraints unique are on R(name) and C(name) S(name).
```

So actually we are constructing implicitly a hierarchy

```
+-Field1
     +-Field2
        +-Field3
          +-Field4
             +-Field5
               +-Field6_Field7
```

means

```
+-CodeR
   +-R
     +-CodeC
          +-C
             +-CodeS
               +-S
```

So my question is **How to ensure data integrity**  (like done programmatically via java code and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428372/detect-repeated-tuples-fi-j-1-fi-j-fi-j1-on-txt-file-using-java) ) 
when I need To insert a new Line either manually by UI 
or by appending that line (in second third ....nth iteration uploading csv file) 
and to be sure [that not to enable data to end up on DB with repeated tuples [fi,(j-1), fi,j ,fi,j+1] ] 
and alert user That his proposed data is rejected ?

To be more clear
**Is there a way to add constraints in neo4j to ensure that each Tuple of Names [FatherXNodeName,XNodeName,ChildXNodeName] is never repeated on my DB ?**

This is how I upload csv file to neo4j.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:///the-file-name.csv\" as "
                            + "line FIELDTERMINATOR \',\' " + "MERGE (r:R{r: line.R}) "
                            + "ON CREATE SET r.description=line.R "
                            + "ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_R " + "ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) "
                            + "MERGE (c:C {cName:line.C}) " + "ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_C "
                            + "ON CREATE SET c.r=line.R "
                            + "ON CREATE SET c.rIdentifier=line.CODE_R " + "ON CREATE SET c.z=line.CODE_C "
                            + "ON CREATE SET c.description=line.C " + "ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) "
                            + "WITH c,r,line " + "MERGE (c)-[:IS_A_C_BELONGING_TO]->(r) "
                            + "MERGE (s:S {sName:line.S}) "
                            + "ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_S " + "ON CREATE SET s.r=line.R "
                            + "ON CREATE SET s.rIdentifier=line.CODE_R " + "ON CREATE SET s.c=line.C "
                            + "ON CREATE SET s.cIdentifier=line.CODE_C "
                            + "ON CREATE SET s.description=line.S " + "ON CREATE SET s.z=line.S "
                            + "ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) " + "WITH s,c,r,line "
                            + "MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_THAT_R]->(r) " + "WITH s,c,r,line "

                            + "MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_S_BELONGING_TO_THAT_C]->(c)"
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176451/discussion-on-question-by-schwertfisch-neo4j-constraints-to-ensure-a-tuple-to-be).

Comment: Related: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453151/create-nodes-depending-on-certain-condition-in-neo4j) question covers doing conditional creates. (reply in the chat if this solution works for you)